# Update the flagging popup for question of out scope for meta

Tags: feature-request, meta, close-reasons, off-topic

I agree with the first two sentences displayed.

I don't think the third sentence is necessary in here. It doesn't seem to relate to the off-topic reason. Please remove it or update it.

[image]

Comment: It is shown here because most of users who ask here are question ban on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @hims056 I disagree with the usage of the work *most*.  I see more programming questions from people who just wander in with no activity on SO.  But yes it does happen.

Comment: do you know that for a fact? IMO if an user is banned from asking at SO, he wouldn't come here to ask a programming question, he would rather come here to ask why he's banned and what to do next. In that case we wouldn't have used the off-topic flag

Comment: @psubsee2003 and mehow: I can confirm that more users wander in here asking programming questions because they are banned than asking why they are banned.

Comment: really? that's very interesting. I am not saying youre lying - im just totally suprised. Also, this isn't always the case so even if it does fit *most* of the situations I still think it will be irrelevant in the remaining cases.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn i would believe that but it still doesn't cover most programming questions though.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Oh I misread your comment. Yeah we have plenty of programming questions coming from people mistaking MSO for the main site without necessarily having been banned or having ever asked a question on the main site. And I have a hard time blaming them; the two sites look so much alike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting on meta because you are question banned on Stack Overflow does happen, and it happens routinely, however, it is not most users as it the commonly held believe, in my opinion.  I believe there was a period of time when it did happen more frequently, but education combined with more and more banned users who are unfamiliar with Meta's existence (especially due to moving the ban message to the Help Center) has reduced people intentionally posting on meta.

These types of questions are deleted quickly, so it is difficult to make a fair assessment after the fact (unless you are a mod), but it is one of the items I check before voting to close a programming question on meta.

In my experience, most of the programming questions are from users who have zero activity on SO, usually are brand new accounts, and usually just wander in.  I don't think we yet know what causes the users to post here instead of on SO.  The sites do look very similar, and not everyone reads the big message in the sidebar under "How to Ask".  Usually it is users who speak English as a 2nd language so the word *meta* might not mean anything (and yes I know that meta is from ancient Greek, but most users who post programming questions here seem to be native speakers of languages that did not derive from Greek and Latin).

That being said, because it does happen often enough, I don't necessary think we need to remove the *see also* sentence here, but I would not object if it were removed, simply because I don't think it is prevalent anymore.

Comment: Frankly English is my first language and "meta" wasn't exactly part of my day to day vernacular before stack exchange

Comment: @Richard Tingle: That's because "meta" is a loanword (or loan-prefix?) from Greek :P